# How to implement a generic adaptor for my C++ api to Python (like Boost.Python does)?

Tags: python, c++, boost

I have made a C++ program with some classes (having some methods) which I want to make scriptable with Python3. At runtime, the program loads some Python scripts from somewhere and executes it. The scripts shall be able to call some of my C++ methods in order to control program behaviour. Probably, this is a common plug-in scenario.

What I've done so far is to embed Python's C-API and to handcraft some `PyMethodDef` and `PyModuleDef` stuff. I was also able to get complete class wrappers by creating `PyTypeObject` instances.

Unfortunately, it does not seem feasible to me to proceed this way. I need to implement a mechanism, which allows me to specify my api somewhere and have it automatically available in the Python world. This is very much one part of what Boost.Python offers. The idea to just use this library and be lucky is probably a very reasonable one.

However, I began to try to implement it on my own (because I don't love external dependencies and primarily because I am interesting in learning).

My successes so far unfortunately are not worth mentioning, since every idea seem to run in a dead end :-/

The `PyMethodDef` structure needs to be filled with something like a `PyObject* *(PyObject*,PyObject*)` function pointer. So I seem to have to provide one plain function (not even a method of some advantageously templated class) for each of my C++ methods, which translates between the `PyObject`s and native C++ values and executes the C++ method on a certain instance.

My first idea was to write a template class, which somehow gets my native method as template argument. In the first run, I restricted the implementation to only one certain method signature, lets say only `void*(int)`. My hope was to see how I can make it more flexible later on. But even with this restriction, I was unable to pass something useful to the `PyTypeObject`. My template class of course can have some instances, but then I only have a method but nothing I can put in the function pointer there. A static method circumvents polymorphism, so this also does not seem to be the solution.

Can anybody explain what is the very basic approach of Boost.Python achieving this goal? Neither reading the code nor the manual gave an idea so far, since it actually does far far more than what I want. I would restrict my api to just use bool, int, some string representation and pointers to other api objects as parameters and return values. I do not need most of the additional magic like translation of exceptions and so on. I want to get a KISS solution.

Otherwise, can anybody give a hint like ...

- how to design my template class in order to make it match, or
- how to achieve more flexibility than just having `void*(int)` methods in the api in a smart but simple way, or
- how to solve the problem in a probably completely different way (avoiding to become trapped into the XY problem ^^)

?

One further design goal is worth mentioning: If even possible, I want to decouple my api specification from Python-specific stuff. In theory, it should be possible to also embed a JavaScript-or-whatever interpreter on top of the same api specification without having to touch it.

More and more I suspect that some parts of my goals are hardly reachable, but I hope somebody here can at least give some new direction of thought.

Comment: Maybe you should check out Swig http://www.swig.org/tutorial.html?

Comment: Thank you, this really is a completely different way. Maybe I later on will resign and fall back to something like that. At the moment, I try to not introduce such an amount of additional apparatus. Since SWIG seems to require an additional build step, this is even worse than using Boost.Python in terms of additional dependencies. On the other hand, this approach would give the (script-)language-agnostic solution which even Boost.Python does not offer.

Answer (score 2):

`Can anybody explain what is the very basic approach of Boost.Python achieving this goal?`

Python already has a system to load `dll`, they are called `extension modules`. Boost.Python can compile source code to produce one. You write a little wrapper to declare a function callable from Python, and template metaprogramming magic helps to detect what types the C++ function takes and returns, so that it can emit the right code to convert those from/to the equivalent Python types.

So basically Boost.Python implementation is a type identification and conversion system that interfaces with the Python C API which does the heavy lifting.
You can look e.g. [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/internals.html)

Comment: The 'template metaprogramming magic' is what is interesting for me in detail. My program is runnable and already has a Python3 integration by means of its C API. But manually writing all the wrappers for my classes is what I not want to do. Instead, I try to get an idea how to implement that 'type identification and conversion system', like Boost.Python also does, but on my own, and much simpler. Currently, I fail even before all that type identification would happen, just because I don't see a way to create the functions I can give into the `PyMethodDef` structure. I'll read your linked text.